# How compiler will know to execute methods when any class implements ITestListener interface

Tags: testng

How does the compiler know that I have to execute on `TestFailure/onFinish/onStart/onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage/onTestSkipped/onTestStart` depending on tests status?

Comment: Could you explain the question? The job of TestNG is to execute methods, call listeners and provide results. So if the question is: "How TestNG do its job?", then you can have a look to its sources.

Comment: Suppose I have to do some tasks when tests fail and I will define particular tasks in onTestFailure method. So how compiler know that it should execute onTestFailure method when tests fail.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG uses [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to configure itself for listener usage. To let TestNG framework to know how to work with your custom listener you need to

1. Apply to your class one of the TestNG listeners contracts (implement one of the [TestNG Listener Interfaces](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners)).
2. Let TestNG framework know that it has to use that implementation by one of the options:

   - [Specifying listeners with testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml)
   - [Specifying listeners in Java](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml)
   - [Specifying listeners with ServiceLoader](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader)